# Translating the companion object in scala to Python

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

I have translated  the  below Spark Scala code to  a Python version.

```
package wscalalearning00
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

object wtry001 {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

     Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
   class BballStatCounter extends Serializable {
          val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
          var missing: Long = 0

          def add(x: Double): BballStatCounter = {
             if (x.isNaN) {
                  missing += 1
                } else {

                stats.merge(x)
                }
                this
              }

  }
 object BballStatCounter extends Serializable {
  def apply(x: Double) = new BballStatCounter().add(x)
}

     // Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Word Count").setMaster("local")) 
    val testData = (1 to 10000).toArray.map(x=>x.toDouble)
    val stats1 = sc.parallelize(testData)
    val stat3 = stats1.map(b=>BballStatCounter(b))
    stat3.foreach(println)        

 }
}
```

Python version:

```
 import math
    import findspark
    findspark.init()
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.statcounter import StatCounter
    class BballStatCounter(object):

        stats = StatCounter()
        missing=0

        @staticmethod
        def add(x):
            print("add")
            if math.isnan(x):
                BballStatCounter.missing += x
            else:
               BballStatCounter.stats.merge(x)
            return BballStatCounter.stats

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("SparkExampleRDD").setMaster("local")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    testData =map(lambda x: float(x),range(0,10000))
    stats1 = sc.parallelize(testData)
    print(stats1)
    stat3 = stats1.map(lambda b: BballStatCounter.add(b))
    stat3.foreach(print)
```

On executing the above Python code, it prints `(count: 22, mean: 10.5, stdev: 6.34428877022, max: 21.0, min: 0.0)` where as the Scala code prints something like this `BballStatCounter$2@7a811dd5`.I think that  Scala code is returning  instances  of same class. Please let me know if my general approach and/or syntax are wrong. Thanks.

Comment: One thing that jumps out is that `BballStatCounter.missing = +other.missing` should *probably* be `BballStatCounter.missing += other.missing`

Comment: Is/should merge be a static method - if not it should have a self parameter first. If you posted a proper Minimal Complete Verifiable Example including everything needed to show the result you are getting it might be possible to run your code and debug it, but as you haven't, you'll have to do that yourself. Life's too short for too many thought experiments with strange code. See https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @barny. As per your input I have added minimal verifiable code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class BballStatCounter:

   def __init__(self):
      self.stats = StatCounter()
      self.missing = 0

    @staticmethod
    def add(x):
        stats = StatCounter()
        missing = 0
        if math.isnan(x):
            BballStatCounter.missing += x
        else:
            BballStatCounter.stats.merge(x,stats,missing)


    def merge(other,stats,missing):
       # stats = BballStatCounter.StatCounter()
        #other = BballStatCounter()
        BballStatCounter.stats.merge(other.stats)
        BballStatCounter.missing = +other.missing
        return self
```

then do

```
stat3 = stats1.map(lambda b: BballStatCounter.add(b))
stat3.foreach(print)
```

I may not give you the right code because I have very little understanding of what the functions are doing. just focus on how I am passing variables between functions.--
hope u find your answer.

Comment: `StatCounter` has a pre-defined  method called `merge()`.`add()`   invoke `merge()` from `StatCounter`. Added to this,  should the method `add()` return something similar to `this`.

Comment: Updated  the minimal working code.What is the difference between creating a `stats`  inside  class and creating a `stats`  inside static method? I am novice to Python programming, try to explore this language. So this question popped out?